# Tensorflow: AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scipy

I get the following error when trying to use tensorflow:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "C:\Users\J\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
>     from tensorflow.python import *   File "C:\Users\J\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
>     import numpy as np   File "C:\Users\J\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
>     from . import add_newdocs   File "C:\Users\J\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
>     from numpy.lib import add_newdoc   File "C:\Users\J\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
>     from . import scimath as emath   File "C:\Users\J\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\scimath.py", line 21, in <module>
>     import numpy.core.numerictypes as nt AttributeError: module 'numpy.core' has no attribute 'numerictypes'
> ```

I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions on what appears to be the same issue.

Comment: Can you share the code line where this error came.

Comment: I just used import tensorflow as tf

Comment: Did you try again after  upgrading your numpy to 1.19 .5 ?